# Link a range of vertically ordered rows, to a horizontal range of columns

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a range function in Google Spreadsheets where I can link the values of `SheetA!A1:A10` to `SheetB!A1:J1`? So basically rotating the values from rows to columns.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `TRANSPOSE(array_or_range)` ([documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)).

So, for example, in A1 write `=TRANSPOSE(SheetA!A1:A10)`.

Comment: ah great, works perfect. thx

Comment: Great! Please mark it as the correct answer, by pressing the outlined tick next to the question.